# How can I return an array constructed using the data emitted by an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function which receives an observable returned by a service. I need this function to iterate over the data emitted by the Observable and to construct an array based on the data received.

I can understand how to construct the array in the way that I want, but what I can't understand is how to return the array.

```
getTop5Crypto() : string[] {

    let top5CryptoIds : string[] = [];
    this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.data;
      for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        top5CryptoIds.push(data[i].baseId)
      }
    });

    return top5CryptoIds; //<-- Will return empty array
  }
```

In the above function I construct the array and then return it. However since the return command is outside of the async code, it will be executed before the async code, which means the function will return an empty array.

If I place the return inside of the `next` observable function, so that it is inside the async code, then the compiler gives an error because not all of the paths within the function will return a value. If I have two return commands, one inside and one outside of the async code then we are back at the first problem.

Update: Whole class

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  //cryptos: string[] = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'litecoin']
  cryptoDetails: CryptoDetail[];

  constructor(private cryptoService: CryptoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoDetails = new Array();

    let ids : string[] = this.getTop5Crypto();
    this.getCryptoData(ids);

    const source = interval(5000).subscribe(val => this.getCryptoData(ids))

  }

  getCryptoData(ids: string[]){
    this.cryptoDetails = [];
    console.log("get crypto")
    for(let crypto of ids){
      this.cryptoService.getCryptoInfo(crypto).subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        let cryptoDetail = new CryptoDetail(data.id, data.rateUsd, data.symbol);
        this.cryptoDetails.push(cryptoDetail);

      })
    }
  }

  async getTop5Crypto() : Promise<string[]> {

    let top5CryptoIds : string[] = [];
    await this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.data;
      for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        top5CryptoIds.push(data[i].baseId)
      }
    });

    return top5CryptoIds;
  }
```

Comment: Please, see my updated code in my answer

Comment: What do you want to do with this data @Jake12342134? I dont understand why you want to return as `string[]` as opposed to `Observable<string[]>`

Comment: @Jake12342134 as if you want to use this within your template then you can simply use the `async` pipe on an `*ngFor` loop to use this data. Can give a full answer to this if I know what you are needing the data to do once returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap()` to emit each array item using a `from()`, and then map to `baseId` to emit the IDs. If you want to limit how many are emitted use `take(5)` and to finally emit all values as an array use `toArray()`.

```
getTop5Crypto() : Observable<string[]> {
    return this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().pipe(
        switchMap(res => from(res.data)),
        map(data => data.baseId),
        take(5),
        toArray()
    );
}
```

Comment: This returns an `Observable<string[]>` however, what am I supposed to do with that? The whole point is to get a `string[]` I can use.

Comment: @Jake12342134 well, that's actually not the point. You've mixed together reactive programming, async/wait, promises and linear programming. Angular uses reactive programming as the recommended paradigm.

Comment: So can you suggest code changes for me? If something is inherently wrong with my code I'd like to know how to fix it.

Comment: @Jake12342134 it's not wrong. It's just mixed. It's difficult for people to answer mixed styles. I will update my answer, but I have to run out for a bit. I'll update it later.

Answer (score -1):

To do that you shouldnt subscribe to observable, you can return an observable with value or use async/await, transform your observable to promise with toPromise().

In your case you are return a value that is not be resolved at the moment of return

```
async getTop5Crypto() : Promise<string[]> {

    let top5CryptoIds : string[] = [];
    let top5CryptoIds = await this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          top5CryptoIds.push(data[i].baseId)
       }
     });
    ).toPromise()

retrun top5CryptoIds 


  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In general the best practice is to return an observable and not the internal data.

If still you want to read the value you can do it with a 'one time read' using `take(1)`:

```
getTop5Crypto() : string[] {

    let top5CryptoIds : string[] = [];
    this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.data;
      for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        top5CryptoIds.push(data[i].baseId)
      }
    });

    return top5CryptoIds;
  }
```

> When you are interested in only the first emission, you want to use
>   take. Maybe you want to see what the user first clicked on when they
>   entered the page, or you would want to subscribe to the click event
>   and just take the first emission. Another use-case is when you need to
>   take a snapshot of data at a particular point in time but do not
>   require further emissions. For example, a stream of user token
>   updates, or a route guard based on a stream in an Angular application.

Comment: But I'm already returning an observable from the cryptoService, if I return an observable from this then I'm just returning observables for the sake of returning them. That doesn't make sense. The whole point of this function is to receive the observable and then do something with the data.

Comment: This case doesnt work, because you are return a value that is resolve in observable

Comment: can you post the usage?

Comment: @AlonYampolski The usage of what?

Comment: what are you doing with the returned value from `getTop5Crypto()`?

Comment: @AlonYampolski I've updated the op with the full class.

Comment: i see that the top reason for this is to get the `cryptoDetails` and i guess that you plan on displaying it in your component..., in this case why not using an observable with pipe async?